# R simulation function based on psych package not saving values

Tags: r, function, psych

I'm trying to write a function for `R` that uses two packages: `simsem` and `psych`. In a nutshell, I want the function to allow me to specify a size for each random sample to be drawn using `simsem`, to specify options for factor analysis (`fa`) to be run on each sample using `psych`, and then to save values from the `fa` model of each sample in a data-frame, so that I can later aggregate across them.

The function, however, is not currently working; no values are being saved in the target data-frame from any of the repetitions of the function.

Reproducible example and my function code below. Really appreciate any insight into what's going awry.

```
#Install and call simsem and psych package, to simulate datasets based on population model, and fit fa model
install.packages("simsem")
library(simsem)

install.packages("psych")
library(psych)

#Specify Population Model
popModel<-"
f1 =~ 0.7*y1 + 0.7*y2 + 0.7*y3
f2 =~ 0.5*y4 + 0.5*y5 + 0.5*y6
f1 ~~ 1*f1
f2 ~~ 1*f2
f1 ~~ 0.50*f2
y1 ~~ 0.51*y1
y2 ~~ 0.51*y2
y3 ~~ 0.51*y3
y4 ~~ 0.75*y4
y5 ~~ 0.75*y5
y6 ~~ 0.75*y6
"

#Function: User specifies number of reps, sample size, number of factors, rotation and extraction method
#Then for each rep, a random sample of popModel is drawn, a FA model is fit, and two logical values are saved
#in data.frame fit
sample.efa = function(rep, N, nfac, rotation, extract){
 fit = data.frame(RMSEA= logical(0), TLI = logical(0)) #create empty data frame with two columns
 for(i in seq_len(rep)){
    dat = generate(popModel, N) #draw a random sample of N size from popModel
    model = fa(dat, nfactors = nfac, rotate = rotation, fm = extract, SMC = TRUE, alpha = .05) #fit FA model with user specified options from function
    store = data.frame(RMSEA=all(model$rms < .08), TLI = all(model$TLI > .90)) #save two logical values in "store"
names(store) = names(fit) #give "store" same names as target data-frame
    fit=rbind(fit, store) #save values from each iteration of "store" in target data-frame "fit"
  }
}

#Run test of function with small number of reps (5) of sample sizes of 200
set.seed(123)
sample.efa(5, N = 200, nfac = 2, rotation = "promax", extract = "ml")
```

Comment: `for(i in rep)`... maybe try `for(i in seq_len(rep))`

Comment: Sorry, fixed an error in the popModel code. Also, tried your suggestion @cory and I got a bunch of warnings to the effect of 'In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "X.RMSEA.") :  invalid factor level, NA generated', and no data-frame was generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the names of your dataframe incorrectly...

```
sample.efa = function(rep, N, nfac, rotation, extract){
  fit = data.frame(RMSEA= logical(0), TLI = logical(0)) #create empty data frame with two columns
  for(i in seq_len(rep)){
    dat = generate(popModel, N) #draw a random sample of N size from popModel
    model = fa(dat, nfactors = nfac, rotate = rotation, fm = extract, SMC = TRUE, alpha = .05) #fit FA model with user specified options from function
    store = data.frame(RMSEA=all(model$rms < .08), TLI = all(model$TLI > .90)) #save two logical values in "store"
    names(store) = names(fit) #give "store" same names as target data-frame
    fit=rbind(fit, store) #save values from each iteration of "store" in target data-frame "fit"
  }
  return(fit)
}
```

Also, you may want to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your dataframes to avoid problems later...

Comment: That eliminates the warnings I was getting from your code, but I'm still not getting the created data-frame I want (I'll update my original post with your amendments)

Comment: 1. It's not my code... it's yours. Don't blame me. 2. You forgot to return your dataframe from the function. I've edited your code in my reply above.

Comment: I apologize--I wasn't intending to seem like I was blaming you. Quite the opposite; I'm posting here because programming is a challenge for me. The return(fit) line solved the problem I was having, so thank you.